# Subsequently disable caching of a HTML file without PHP

Tags: php, html, caching

There's some rather old, small website I need to manage these days.
It's stored on a webspace which supports NO PHP (must be a contract from last century) and I decided to work with iframes (I know, I know), just so I don't have to implement the basic structure including the menu in every html file. The loaded iframe content either are simple html files or pdf's.

The caching always was a problem with this site, people had to press reload on their own, so it refreshed the source code, but mostly a hard refresh, including the deletion of the cache was needed.

I included `<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">`, which works like a charm for me and others, but apparently not for everyone (if the page does not reload, the browser will never see the meta tag). This probably is due to some bug of an ancient browser version. Since PHP is not an option, I currently am stuck, hopefully someone got an idea how to get this to work.

*I'm currently discussing a server change to something modern including PHP and a database with the responsible person, but this process can take a while.*

Answer (score 0):

If a browser has cached the page, and decided that the page is still valid, you can't invalidate the page other than from changing it's URL.

(The problem would be the same with PHP pages.)

To avoid this in the future, just add a `<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="must-revalidate, max-age=0">` so that the browser always verifies if a newer version exists.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add that, hopefully the server situation will change asap.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look to your server configuration, because it sounds like the server is sending cache control headers.

If it is Apache, you might have `mod_expires` or `mod_headers` available.  Please update your question with information about the server.

Comment: Thanks, I'll get in contact with the person in charge, hopefully I'll get a quick reply on this.